# Silverlight Project - Slide-in and out Panel - How?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I don't know what exactly this feature is, but I would like to simulate this in my Silverlight project.  I am a C# developer and am moving to Silverlight and Expression Studio (Blend) for richer UX.  Let's say I have some user controls and would like them to come into the screen (slide-in and out) as shown in the following site I found:

http://www.templatemonster.com/silverlight-templates/28722.html

On the menu, as one clicks on the menu item, the 'screen' slides to the left and then a new 'screen' slides in from the left to right.

I really want to learn this stuff, but don't know what these 'features' are called?  For example what are these 'screens' called in the xaml world?  Also, what is the 'slide-in/out' called in the xaml world?  Can someone point me to a good article/whitepaper?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly Silverlight/WPF is **really** good at this kind of stuff. The framework guys did a great job engineering xaml to be as flexible as possible.

That being said admittingly there’s a lot to get before attempting these sort of things
like [ResourceDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29), [Triggers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-4-Data-templates-and-tri), [Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger.actions?view=net-5.0), [Storyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms742868%28v=vs.100%29), Animation (Keyframe/[Double](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/your-first-animations-using-xaml-and-silverlight-double-animation-part-ii/)...) , Templating, [Styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109212512/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/GeekAgilistMercenary/archive/2010/03/22/styles-for-xaml-silverlight-amp-wpf.aspx)
but once you get these metaphors its way easier.

Heres the rundown with some primers.

- [Keyframe animation](http://joel.neubeck.net/2008/01/silverlight-how-to-frame-by-frame-animation/) is what this is mostly relying on with some
- [Triggers and Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/expression/an-introduction-to-behaviors-triggers-and-actions) to orchestrate the
- [Visual States](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/06/10/visual-state) which is what the panel looks like 'Open' / 'Closed'

Heres a sample for you pulling this stuff together.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CentrePanelStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="350"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.3000000" To="Open">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="350">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="800">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="Open" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.3000000" To="Closed">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.6000000" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="800"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Closed"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Fill="#A1808080" />
    <Grid Name="CentrePanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="800" Height="500">
        <Border CornerRadius="3"
                Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="350" Margin="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         
                <Rectangle Fill="Beige" /> 
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFDDDCF5" />

                <Button  
                    Content="Close"  
                    Width="79"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,130,0,0" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ic:GoToStateAction StateName="Closed"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>   
            
                <Button  Content="Open" Width="81"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,85,0,0" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ic:GoToStateAction StateName="Open"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Grid> 
        
        </Border>
    </Grid>        
    
       
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this all afternoon! Your post here is exactly what I needed, well, almost! Do you know if it's possible to use one button to slide the panel in and out instead of needing two? Other than that, this was just what I needed, thanks.