# slide-in search box on windows phone (like in the bing maps app)

Tags: windows-phone-7, panel, slidedown

In the bing maps app on windows phone, when I click the search button I get a search box sliding in from the top of the screen, and the keyboard sliding in from the bottom. I want to achieve the same behaviour in my own windows phone app (based around a bing map control).

I will want a few drop-in boxes, such as for setting up a filter (which will need a few check boxes and text entry), and adding an item (which will require a text entry for the name, and ideally still allow the map in the main panel to be panned to fine-tune the location of the item).

I'm pretty sure the keyboard comes up automatically when a textbox gets focus, but I'm not sure what might be the best approach for dropping in the search box. It looks like it would need something with storyboards/animations/projections, but I haven't found a clear standard approach so far, and I want to make sure I do it the right way from the start (as I don't really have time to do it twice).

Is there a standard/best practice way to achieve the effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight Project - Slide-in and out Panel - How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067656/silverlight-project-slide-in-and-out-panel-how)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you don't need a single line of code. You can express the whole animation using XAML. Get a text on Silverlight and read the chapters on animation with particular reference to [storyboards and Easing](http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Storyboard-Animation-Easing-Demonstration.aspx).

Comment: That looks good - I'm under a lot of time pressure at the moment, with this project nearer the bottom of the pile, so links to examples would be great too.