# How do I create an expaning panel in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

I'm a rank newbie at animations and so on in Siverlight, and have a need to create an expandable panel, which can be used as a help facility. The idea is that the screen would have a small button at the top-right, and when clicked, this would animate the width of a panel containing help info from zero to some width. Clicking the button again would shrink the help panel back to zero width.

This sounds like it ought to be really easy, and in WPF it is, but as Silverlight doesn't seem to support a lot of the functionality of WPF, I'm struggling badly here.

I looked at the expander control from the toolkit, but as far as I can see, this doesn't do what I want, as the control always takes up the same screen area. I want the expandable panel to disappear when it's not in use.

Anyone able to provide a simple example of how this could be done? Note that I'm using SL4, not SL5.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to Expression Blend, this can (almost) all be done in XAML.

[This is a good place to get started](http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/eyesofblend/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'd already seen that site, but it didn't give me enough detailed info to get going. I was looking for something more specific. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found another SO question where someone posted XAML to do something almost identical...

[Silverlight Project - Slide-in and out Panel - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067656/silverlight-project-slide-in-and-out-panel-how)

Hope this helps someone else :)